# Why does $f(0)=\int f(x) \, d\mu =\frac14$ and $f$ extremal at $0$ imply $\mu(\{0\})=1$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I just read a paper by Abner Shimony (The Status of the Principle of
Maximum Entropy), and he is making a claim about a Lebesgue integral
in appendix A that I don't fully understand yet.

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function which has strictly one extremum at $x=0$
(it's a maximum, but according to Shimony that doesn't matter). We
also know that

$$
f(0)=1/4
$$

and

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)d\mu=1/4
$$

where $\mu$ is a probability measure. Shimony says that it follows
that $\mu$ puts all of its weight on the point $0$, i.e.
$\mu(\{0\})=1$. Why, and how can you show this to be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ has a strict maximum at $x = 0$, so $f(x) < 1/4$ for $x \ne 0$.
Let
$L_n = \{x: f(x) < 1/4 - 1/n \}$.  Then 
$$\frac{1}{4} = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\; dx = \int_{L_n} f(x)\; d\mu + \int_{\mathbb R \backslash L_n} f(x)\; d\mu \le \left(\dfrac{1}{4} - \dfrac{1}{n}\right) \mu(L_n) + \dfrac{1}{4} (1 - \mu( L_n)) = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{\mu(L_n)}{n}$$ 
so $\mu(L_n) = 0$.  Now by countable additivity
$$\mu(\mathbb R \backslash \{0\}) = \mu\left( \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} L_n \right) = 0$$